# Environmental path to Python not working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, installation, environment-variables

I have Installed Python 3.4 onto a new PC. Python works but I am trying to get pip to work on this. I have made a path for Python which is below.

```
C:\Python34\python.exe
```

When i run the below code

```
C:\Windows\System32>pip install python-docx


'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: You could try entering just 'Py' in the Cmd line

Answer (score 7):

It seems that you haven't configured your `PATH` variable correctly. In order to do so:

- Hold down the Win key and press Pause.
- Click Advanced System Settings.
- Click Environment Variables.
- Append `;C:\Python34` to the `PATH` variable.
- Restart Command Prompt.

(You may also just run `set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;C:\Python34` in the `cmd`)

Further information is available in [The Official Python Installation Guide for Windows](https://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html).

Comment: This doesn't make sense... Can you write the command you use to run python and the exact error?

Comment: I have Only put in the word python.

Comment: That's... What? Please edit your question and show exactly the command and where it was executed + the full error... Or I couldn't help..